# R Querying Dates in one data frame with dates from a separate data frame

Tags: r, date

After searching for a few hours, it seams I can't find a solution to the following problem. I've got 2 data frames, one contains a column of observation dates, the other contains a start date and and end date:

for example:

```
head(x)
station temp obsdate
311820  65.0 1973-01-01
311821  62.0 1973-01-02
etc...

head(seasonDates)
season startDate    endDate
A      1973-11-01   1974-06-30
B      1974-11-01   1975-06-30
C      1975-11-01   1976-06-30
etc...
```

I'd like to assign the 'season' from the 'seasonDates' data frame to the 'x' data frame if the observation date 'obsdate' is within the range of dates indicated by 'startDate' to 'endDate'. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I was hoping I could use a conditional to solve this:
`ifelse(x$obsdate>=seasonDates$startDate,x$season=seasonDates$season,0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the three date columns are of class "Date" :

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from x left join seasonDates on
        (obsdate between startDate and endDate)")
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. For some reason when I ran this I ended up with duplicate matches, with one of the duplicates rows matched incorrectly. However, if I cast the start dates as numerics it worked perfectly. I checked that all dates were of class "Date" and looked for obvious mistakes. Obviously, my SQL talents are less than stellar so I suspect it is related to how I am trying use the left join. Big Thanks!

Comment: @austin, If you post it in reproducible form or send it to me I can look at it.

Comment: You have been more than a great help and I don't want to take any more of your time. I'm sure it's on my side and I need to take the time to update my SQL skill set. Thank you for your offer.